# How to hg ignore filename with no extension?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

**Mercurial** can be configured to **ignore** files whose filename have a certain extension. For example, `*.txt` files can be ignored by adding this to `~/.hgignore`:

```
syntax: glob
*.txt
```

How can I setup my .hgignore file to ignore files whose filenames have **no extensions**? For example, files named `foobar` and `abracadabra` should be ignored, but `foobar.cpp` and `abracadabra.c` should be tracked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `regexp` syntax instead since it's not possible with `glob`:

```
syntax: regexp
^[^.]+$
```

PS: you can add it right after your `syntax: glob` section

Answer (score 3):

If you have a small list of files without extension that you want to ignore, then you can just list them as glob patterns:

```
syntax: glob
foobar
abracadabra
```

If you want to ignore all files without an extension, then things become more difficult. If you use the regexp provided by zerkms,

```
syntax: regexp
^[^.]+$
```

then you will also ignore *directories* without an "extension", that is directories without `.` in their names such as `src`, and so on.

Because Mercurial matches files and directories top-down while traversing your working copy, and because it doesn't distinguish between files and directories when matching against the patterns in the `.hgignore` file, you **cannot** include a directory while ignoring files with the same name.

(You can simulate the opposite: by ignoring `foobar/` in regexp syntax you end up ignoring all files inside `foobar/` while not ignoring a file named `foobar` in another directory.)